# how to bind a form data and rowselected data from jqGrid to server?

Tags: jquery, forms, jqgrid, bind

I have a jgrid and on selectiing and submitting the row I have to submit the for data with that url which contains two date field... How can I bind the values of form and selected row together  on submit to server?

Nay help will be appreciated.. Thanks!

**Update 1:**

```
    jQuery(".sorder").click(function() {
    var earliestDate = jQuery("input#e").val();
    var latestTimeDate = jQuery("input#e").val();
    var grid = jQuery("#orderPreview");
    var id = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    if (id) {
        var ret = grid.jqGrid('getRowData', id);
    }

    $.ajax( {
        type : "POST",
        url : "/cpsb/internalOrderList.do",
        data : {
            method : "create",
            lpn : ret.licensePlateNumber,
            sku : ret.sku,
            description:ret.description,
            cases:ret.caseQuantity,
            hold:ret.isHeld,
            earliestDate:earliestDate,
            latestTimeDate:latestTimeDate
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: How you make "submitting the row"? Are the selected row in the inline editing mode and you want save it?

Comment: @Oleg my application is like shopping cart where I add rows frm a different grid ...than I need to send all rows from that grid (with addition to that latest time and earliest time from there...my approach is updated in my question

Comment: I am adding the value from those input like this way  var earliestDate = jQuery("input#e").val();
    var latestTimeDate = jQuery("input#e").val();
but problem is that from  orderPreview grid I have to submit all rows without have to select + need to send those dates(earliest,latesttimedate)...another problem is that appending so many data with url is a problem ..how server side code will know how many rows were sending..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data from the grid with

```
var gridData = jQuery("#orderPreview").getRowData(); // no rowid parameter
```

then you can use

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/cpsb/internalOrderList.do",
    data: gridData,
    dataType: "json"
});
```

to send the data at once. Because the data will be send per POST and not per GET you have no URL restriction.

By the way in your code you use

```
var earliestDate = jQuery("input#e").val();
var latestTimeDate = jQuery("input#e").val();
```

probably in one of the row the id "e" should be changed.

Comment: @Oleg ....Yes, one id is wrongly copied from my code...one more thing can I append the earliest time and latestTimeDate value since its in a different form but I have to send those values as well with the row data....Thanks!

Comment: @paul: In JavaScript it is extrimly easy to add new property to existing object. Just set there: `gridData.method="create"; gridData.earliestDate=earliestDate; gridData.latestTimeDate=latestTimeDate;`

Comment: @Oleg can I do like this     jQuery(".sorder").click(function() {
        var earliestDate = jQuery("input#e").val();
        var latestTimeDate = jQuery("input#e").val();
        var gridData = jQuery("#orderPreview").getRowData();
        gridData.method = "create";
        gridData.earliestDate=earliestDate; gridData.latestTimeDate=latestTimeDate;
        $.ajax( {
            type : "POST",
            url : "/cpsb/internalOrderList.do",
            data : gridData,
            dataType:"json"
        });

    });

Comment: @paul: Yes, it is what I mean. You should only fix the problem with the usage "input#e" twice.

Comment: when I am trying to send those rows ..I saw &undefine=undefine&undefine=undefine&undefine=undefine....not sure why its shoqing that

Comment: @paul: What can I say. You should verify all and more better debug all. In general it should work.

Comment: i debug it again and find that when I am using data:gridData ...on console I am seeing undefine but when i changed to data:{ method:"create", param:gridData} it works and show me the data in my firebug console....I wanna send the row and earliest , latest time together....so that in server side I will have data in param and can count how many rows are coming from client side