# jqgrid custom action POST data to the server

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

tried looking in the documentation but could not find.

Is there a way in which i can do a post to the server using custom button and not invoke a edit/add screeen?

```
jQuery("#mytreegrid").jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#ptreegrid", 
   {caption:"",title:"Move Up", buttonicon :'ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n', 
     onClickButton:function(){ 
      // calling something similar to onclickSubmit where i can construct 
      // my post body or set urls like onclickSubmit: function(rp_ge, postdata)  
    }
});
```

Help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compare the code which will be executed if the user click on the "Edit" button (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L1689)) with `onClickButton` of the [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) you will see what you should do. You need just get the rowid of the current selected row `selrow` (or selected rows `selarrrow`) and do what you need. To send any information to the server you can use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). To get the row contain of the row you can use [getRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#grid_related_methods) for example. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024075/jqgrid-navigation-based-on-the-selected-row/3024278#3024278) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587480/jquery-modal-dialog-and-jqgrid/3588732#3588732) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816874/jqgrid-howto-send-all-rowdata-in-json-format-to-server/3817174#3817174) old answers for detailes.